# Jquery popup plugin

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, popup

I am looking for a plugin that will popup a full size image WITH HYPERLINK when user clicks the thumbnail image link. I found http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ is useful but I can't add the hyperlink to the full size popup image. Anyone has idea where to get it or how to do it? Thanks a lot!

my jquery:

```
 $('#projects a').lightBox();
```

my html

```
<div id='projects'> 
     <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="image1.jpg" title="test">//I want to add a hyperlink                  
                                                      //when user click the large image
                <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="image2.jpg">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great resource comparing all the different types of light boxes:

http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

You'll want a light box that supports HTML content.

Answer (score 2):

There are many similar plugins that allow arbitrary HTML content in their windows. For example, you can check out [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) or [Lytebox](http://www.dolem.com/lytebox/). I'm sure that there are others too.